# Bencode parser in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, bittorrent

What is the best possible way to go about writing a Bencode Parser in C++. Whilst I am open to the suggestion of an external library which may make the task easier I think that I would learn some valuable lessons in C++ if I wrote my own parser. Keep in mind that I am still open to the suggestion :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd read the spec and implement it. It's relatively simple

Comment: 1) read [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode). 2) Implement it. 3) profit

Comment: It's difficult to know how to answer this.  If you don't want to use an extant parsing library, then you'll need to write your own parser.  It's not possible to give a beginner's guide to parsers in a Stack Overflow question, so I recommend you do some internet research, or get a book on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively straightforward, just read how it works on http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode#section_1for example.

Alternatively, Google found for example this C++ library : https://github.com/kriben/bencode.

You can also get some inspiration from http://effbot.org/zone/bencode.htm, a simple Python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways, apart of re-implementing the wheel again, is to use [libbencode](https://github.com/ybubnov/libbencode) library (I'm the author). It provides template-based approach for building bencode data.

The API is quite limited, but potentially it can fit your needs:

```
// Create an associative array of Bencode values.
bencode::dict d;

d["port wine"] = bencode::make_integer(777);
d["green"] = bencode::make_string("elephant");

// Create a new Bencode output stream
bencode::ostream os(std::cout.rdbuf());

// Put the data to the stream
os << d;
```